# Is it safe to carry $10000?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, money

I am immigrating to Canada and need to carry $12500 with me. Is it safe to carry such amount in cash with me?. 
What is the limit for amount of cash we can carry in a single flight?
(Government of Canada request single immigrants to bring 12500$ as initial settlement fund)

Comment: We can't answer if is it safe -- a better question is what the customs rules are on entry to Canada (you need to declare money in excess of CAN$ 10000) and/or how best to transfer the money safely. It will also matter where you're coming from as they will have their own rules.

Comment: Yes, where are you coming from and are you transiting through any countries? There may be currency controls from your origin country too. In general, I'd strongly advise against it and encourage you to keep the money in banks instead. If the cash is lost or stolen, that could be catastrophic.

Comment: More information is needed to attempt to answer this question of whether it's safe, such as your origin and destination point, the route you're taking, how you're concealing the money, your experience in being aware of your surroundings etc.
But I agree that an alternative means of funds transfer is almost certainly preferable.

Answer (score 4):

Is it safe? If your personal security is good (i.e. nobody knows you have it) then it's as safe as carrying any other sum, but you have a lot to lose if you're unlucky and some malicious individual picks you as their target.

However, you will need to declare the money whenever you cross a border. Specifically, on your arrival in Canada you'll need to declare any amount greater than C$10,000 at Canadian customs and fill in a CBSA declaration card ([Source](http://www.cbsa-asfc.gc.ca/travel-voyage/ttd-vdd-eng.html)). Since these requirements relate to money laundering you'll need a watertight explanation for why you need that much cash and where you got it. Note that this also applies to Traveller's Cheques, banker's drafts and other 'monetary instruments'

There is no limit on the amount you can carry, but the larger the sum, the more likely you will be to have a long conversation with a border guard.

Unless you really, really have no choice, you're much better using a bank to transfer the money.